# В соответствии с каким правилом пунктуации стоит тире?

Tags: пунктуация, тире, сложное-предложение

*Эгикал — один из крупнейших средневековых башенных комплексов горной Ингушетии, расположен он на южном склоне горы Цей-Лоам в двух километрах от реки Ассы.*

Comment: Не имеющие общей конструкции предложения логичней делить тчк/зпт. Либо исключить местоимение из второго и получить единое — с обособленным двумя тире приложением.

Comment: вот и я об этом! данное задание из сборника по подготовке к ЕГЭ‍♀️)))

Comment: Да нормальная пунктуация, бессоюзное соединение, такое часто можно увидеть. Можно, конечно, и точкой разделить, и точкой с запятой. Но запятая тоже неплохой вариант.

Comment: По интонации лучше запятая. Обратим внимание на инверсию:  расположен он. Инверсия так просто не делается.  Как я думаю, так обеспечивается плавный интонационный переход от одной части сообщения к другой,  увеличенной паузы нет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Эгикал — один из крупнейших средневековых башенных комплексов...*

**Правило** ([Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=91), справочник Розенталя):

> **4.** Тире ставится, если оба главных члена предложения выражены количественными числительными или если один из них выражен формой именительного падежа существительного, а другой — числительным либо оборотом с числительным.

**Примеры** из Национального корпуса русского языка:

*Жорж де Ла Тур — один из крупнейших представителей лотарингской школы живописи.

Государственный музей изобразительных искусств имени А. С. Пушкина — один из крупнейших в России музеев мирового искусства.

Академик С. С. Намёткин — один из крупнейших представителей отечественной школы органической химии.

Старая Рязань — один из крупнейших древнерусских городов XII-XIII веков.

Проект «Сахалин-2» — один из крупнейших в мире трубопроводных проектов.*

Comment: а во второй части предложения грамматическая основа «он расположен»?

Comment: @fleurdellyss Да, верно.